# Ant Design TreeSelect async load

Tags: reactjs, antd

I really excited to using Ant Design library, it saves me a lot of time, but there's some flaws or I just misunderstood something.

I am using TreeSelect with async loading.

```
const onLoadData = () => {
  ... // Some api call which changes state "treeData"
}

<TreeSelect
      value={value}
      onChange={onChange}
      loadData={onLoadData}
      treeData={treeData}
/>
```

My problem is that when api logic fails, e.g. API is down, so it return 502, the Tree node falls into never ending loading cycle until API return return "child" data for node. So I figure out that the problem is that when node is expanded it need some "child" nodes.

So according docs I take controll which nodes should be expanded via treeExpandedKeys prop.

```
<TreeSelect
      value={value}
      onChange={onChange}
      loadData={onLoadData}
      treeData={treeData}
      treeExpandedKeys={treeExpandedKeys}
/>
```

So with that, when API call fails I just close node with state treeExpandedKeys. But it has one big problem. When node is once expanded it cannot be closed. Because library doesn't have any function which would return node's id when user click on expand arrow.

Is anybody who encouter same situation? Maybe I just miss something.

Comment: Can you make a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example using [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/)?